# Is it possible for Apache to rename a file to symbolic link value when it is being downloaded?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have two websites where the first one provides a bunch of links to files being download from the second one.

I need the links on the first website to be static while still allowing files to be modified on the back end.

For example, the links would look like:

```
[link to file1] (displayed on server1) -> server2.com/file1.zip
[link to file2] (displayed on server1) -> server2.com/file2.zip
```

On the second server, the files themselves are symbolic links, pointing to files with version values, for example:

```
file1.zip -> file1-1.0.0.0.zip
file2.zip -> file2-1.0.0.0.zip
```

This worked well enough but unfortunately the file name the user sees is "file1.zip" while I would need them to see "file1-1.0.0.0.zip" (value of the symbolic link).

I've solved the problem by using a php file that renames the file as they are being downloaded. Is there another way to solve this problem, for example by properly configured Apache? It would be ideal if I didn't have to maintain a PHP file.

Comment: At first glance that sounds like a use-case for a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewritemap.html) (that links the short permalink filename `file1.zip` to the actual versioned filename `file1-1.0.0.0.zip`)  in combination with a **R** external redirect to the actual file (which will preserve the versioned file name).

Comment: That would work but would end up making my symbolic links useless because I'd need to list everything in my .htaccess file rather than at the OS level, is that right?
Your comment has prompted me to find the following useful page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351271/apache-redirects-based-on-symlinks